# EF Core Migration recreates renamed tables

Tags: .net, entity-framework, database-migration

I'm using .NET 5 Identity package and renamed it's tables as well as used an extension of `IdentityUser`. Now I decided to add few properties to my `User` and apply a migration, but the migration tries to recreate my renamed tables.

Here is my User model:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>, IUser
{
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Username { get => base.UserName; set => base.UserName = value; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool PubliclyVisible { get; set; } //New
    public IEnumerable<User> Trackers { get; set; } //New
    public IEnumerable<User> Tracked { get; set; } //New

}
```

My `DbContext` extension model configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>(b =>
    {
        b.ToTable("Users");
        b.HasMany(b => b.Tracked); //New
        b.HasMany(b => b.Trackers); //New 
        b.Ignore(u => u.Username);
                
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<GPSData>().HasOne(d => d.User);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>(b => b.ToTable("UserClaims"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<int>>(b => b.ToTable("UserLogins"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<int>>(b => b.ToTable("UserTokens"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>(b => b.ToTable("Roles"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<int>>(b => b.ToTable("RoleClaims"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>(b => b.ToTable("UserRoles"));

}
```

I marked the new properties in my `User` as well as additional lines in the configuration with `//New`.

After I run `add-migration AddedTrackingProperties`

I get the following migration that tries to recreate my tables and thus I get an error that `AspNetUserRoles` already exist, when I update the table.

Migration config

```
public partial class AddedTrackingProperties : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetRoles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Roles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Roles", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Users",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Password = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                PubliclyVisible = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                UserName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                Email = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "datetimeoffset", nullable: true),
                LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Users", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "RoleClaims",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                RoleId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_RoleClaims", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_RoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                    column: x => x.RoleId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "GPSData",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Longitude = table.Column<double>(type: "float", nullable: false),
                Latitude = table.Column<double>(type: "float", nullable: false),
                Speed = table.Column<double>(type: "float", nullable: false),
                Timestamp = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                UserId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_GPSData", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_GPSData_Users_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "UserClaims",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                UserId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_UserClaims", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_UserClaims_Users_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "UserLogins",
            columns: table => new
            {
                LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                ProviderDisplayName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                UserId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_UserLogins", x => new { x.LoginProvider, x.ProviderKey });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_UserLogins_Users_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "UserRoles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                UserId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                RoleId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_UserRoles", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_UserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                    column: x => x.RoleId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_UserRoles_Users_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "UserTokens",
            columns: table => new
            {
                UserId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                Value = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_UserTokens", x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider, x.Name });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_UserTokens_Users_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "UserUser",
            columns: table => new
            {
                TrackedId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                TrackersId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_UserUser", x => new { x.TrackedId, x.TrackersId });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_UserUser_Users_TrackedId",
                    column: x => x.TrackedId,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_UserUser_Users_TrackersId",
                    column: x => x.TrackersId,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "RoleNameIndex",
            table: "AspNetRoles",
            column: "NormalizedName",
            unique: true,
            filter: "[NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_GPSData_UserId",
            table: "GPSData",
            column: "UserId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_RoleClaims_RoleId",
            table: "RoleClaims",
            column: "RoleId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_UserClaims_UserId",
            table: "UserClaims",
            column: "UserId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_UserLogins_UserId",
            table: "UserLogins",
            column: "UserId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_UserRoles_RoleId",
            table: "UserRoles",
            column: "RoleId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "EmailIndex",
            table: "Users",
            column: "NormalizedEmail");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "UserNameIndex",
            table: "Users",
            column: "NormalizedUserName",
            unique: true,
            filter: "[NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_UserUser_TrackersId",
            table: "UserUser",
            column: "TrackersId");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "GPSData");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "RoleClaims");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Roles");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "UserClaims");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "UserLogins");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "UserRoles");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "UserTokens");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "UserUser");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "AspNetRoles");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Users");
    }
}
```

So where is the mistake?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @dglozano, Sorry for the late response. Yes, I understand very much the issue, I thought at first that EF Core somehow registers earlier change and provides migration code accordingly. But as you have pointed out, it is not the case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I understand, Entity Framework is generally unable to detect when your intention is to just rename a column/table or actually drop it and create something else, so it ends up scaffolding a migration that drops and recreates the column/table.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#column-renames):

> EF Core is generally unable to know when the intention is to drop a column and create a new one (two separate changes), and when a column should be renamed. If the above migration is applied as-is, all your customer names will be lost. To rename a column, replace the above generated migration with the following:

What you should do in such scenarios is to customize the code of the migration that was automatically scaffolded by EF. In this case, you could take advantage of the methods [`RenameColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.renamecolumn?view=efcore-5.0) and [`RenameTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.renametable?view=efcore-5.0) to specify that in the migration only a rename operation should take place.

Hence, after generating the migration, remove the `Drop` and `Create` statements in both `Up` and `Down` methods and replace them with the corresponding calls to `RenameTable` and `RenameColumn`.

For example:

```
public partial class AddedTrackingProperties : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
            name: "IdentityUserRole", newName: "UserRoles");

       // ...
       // TODO: other necessary rename tables/columns
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
            name: "UserRoles", newName: "IdentityUserRole");

       // ...
       // TODO: other necessary rename tables/columns
    }
}
```